# How to merge few rows into one row when it has a same value in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

I am getting the following table,

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|    quantity |      year |      month |           category |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|         122 |      2012 |          7 | 15                 |
|         100 |      2012 |          7 | 25                 |
|         1029|      2012 |          7 | 10                 |
|         212 |      2012 |          7 | 0                  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

But I want to get it as how we can merge cells in excel

```
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|    quantity |      year |      month |           category |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
|         122 |           |            | 15                 |
|         100 |      2012 |          7 | 25                 |
|         1029|           |            | 10                 |
|         212 |           |            | 0                  |
+-------------+-----------+------------+--------------------+
```

checking if this is possible in MySQL?

Comment: Do you want only the row with the max "category" should show the year and month?

Comment: What you want to do is not really possible in SQL.  A table has rows and each row has columns -- all rows have the same columns.  You would need to do this in the application layer.  Or perhaps do a hack by aggregating strings in the other columns.

Comment: @TheImpaler, no I want each of the category, like how in excel sheet we can merge cells with same common values. As far as I know we cant do that, but just wanted to check if there was a cool function for doing this in SQL level

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yeah I think I should do it in react then after getting the table from mysql.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* find that aggregation is what you really want:

```
select year, month, group_concat(quantity), group_concat(category)
from t
group by year, month;
```

This produces one row for each `year`/`month` combination with a list of the quantities and categories.  You can get fancy and use a newline to separate the values.  They would appear on multiple "lines" but still be one "row".

Note that the ordering is not specified in the question.  And without an `order by` in the `group_concat()` the values for the two columns might not be in the same order as the original data.

Comment: Thanks for this, the new line idea sounds fun, lemme try that.